# I need help implementing signed VarInt's in C++

Tags: c++, varint

I have been working on a program that can connect to a Minecraft Server and exchange packets with it but Minecraft's server packets heavily rely on signed VarInts. On the [site](https://wiki.vg/Protocol) documenting how their communication works is explanation of VarInt and even an [example implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBV1.jpg) of them in Java:

So i followed it and it works for non negative numbers but for negative numbers it's just goes infinitely long. I serched for other means of implementing it but i couldn't find any.

Here is my version it (works as i said only for positive numbers which is not fully what i want)

```
class VarInt
{
public:
    char* data = NULL;
    int length = 0;

    int Read();
    void Write(int value);

    ~VarInt();
private:
    int SEGMENT_BIT_MASK = 0x7F;
    int CONTINUE_BIT_MASK = 0x80;

};

int VarInt::Read()
{
    int value = 0;
    int position = 0;
    byte currentByte;

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        currentByte = data[i];
        value |= (currentByte & SEGMENT_BIT_MASK) << position;

        if ((currentByte & CONTINUE_BIT_MASK) == 0)
            break;

        i++;
        position += 7;

        if (position >= 32)
            std::cout << "VarInt is too Big" << std::endl;
    }
    return value;
};

void VarInt::Write(int value)
{
    bool state = true;
    std::vector<byte> bytes;

    while (state)
    {
        if ((value & ~SEGMENT_BIT_MASK) == 0)
        {
            bytes.push_back(value);
            state = false;
            break;
        }
        bytes.push_back(((value & SEGMENT_BIT_MASK) | CONTINUE_BIT_MASK));
        value >>= 7;
    }

    int bytes_size = bytes.size();

    length = bytes_size;
    data = (char*)malloc(bytes_size);

    int i = 0;
    while (i != bytes_size)
    {
        data[i] = bytes.at(i);
        i++;
    }
};

VarInt::~VarInt()
{

};
```

And here are my means of testing it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MDatatypes.h"

int main()
{
    ndt::VarInt test;
    //Sets value of test to -127
    test.Write(-127);

    //Sets value of test2 to 255
    ndt::VarInt test2;
    test2.Write(255);

    //Outputing length of each Varint in bytes
    std::cout << test.length << '|' << test2.length << std::endl;
    //Outputing the values of each Varint
    std::cout << test.Read() << '|' << test2.Read() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Can you use `std::vector` instead of manual allocation? Using `malloc` in C++ code is generally bad form when `new[]` is right there.

Comment: Can you use a library like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) which already has an implementation?

Comment: @tadman I could but i prefer not to when I know the size and that it won't change

Comment: Why not `std::array` then? These containers are very low cost and can be used for that sort of thing without worrying. It also saves you the hassle of tracking ownership and implementing a destructor. This code has a lot of undefined behavior baked in due to uninitialized variables. It looks like `Write` should actually be your constructor.

Comment: You're already using `std::vector` in there, and then manually crunching the data over. Remember, in C++ you have [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and other tools to do that for you.

Comment: As far as negative numbers not working right, just cast to `uint32_t` (or `uint64_t`) before converting.

Comment: @tadman I will look into Protocol Buffers thanks